# Is it possible to run an .exe file from a CLR function?

Tags: sybase-sql-anywhere, external-environment

Is it possible to run an `.exe` from CLR function with Sybase SQL Anywhere 12?

If yes then I thought about link this function and `.exe` with pipes, is it a good idea or do you have better ideas? If not then thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [xp_cmdshell](http://dcx.sybase.com/1200/en/dbreference/xp-cmdshell-sysproc.html) for doing this.

As a little example from documentation:

```
CALL xp_cmdshell( 'dir > c:\\temp.txt' );
```

But take care: It's not possible to get e.g. STDOUT back into your database without output redirection.